# sharing a git repository to a machine that does not have internet access from one that has

Tags: git, clone, git-clone, git-fetch

I have this setup

```
machineA -> remote server with a repo.git initialized with --bare

machineB -> client that can access to internet and clone repo.git, so it locally will have repo

machineC -> connected in LAN with machineB and no internet access
```

The goal is to make machineC work (in read-only mode) with the machineB repo as if it was the remote one. Because of this, machineB is periodically doing a git fetch from the remote server

I am sharing the local machineB repo via SMB and I am able to clone it from machineC.

The issue is that I am just be able to get the master branch or only the local branches I have on machineB, not all the branches present on machineA.

Is there any command to fetch locally everything or to transform the repo into a .git one?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In machineB, make a mirror clone from machineA

```
git clone --mirror /url/to/machineA/repository
```

In machineC, clone from the mirror repository in machineB

```
git clone /url/to/machineB/repository
```

When the machineC repository needs the latest data from machineA, first update the mirror repository in machineB

```
git remote update
```

and then update the repository in machineC

```
git fetch
```

> The issue is that I am just be able to get the master branch or only
> the local branches I have on machineB, not all the branches present on
> machineA.

In your current situation, you can still fetch all the branches and tags in the machineC repository by

```
git fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

But it's unnatural and confusing. By turning the machineB repository from a non-bare repository to a mirror repository, we can use familiar commands in the machineC repository.

Comment: this is an awesome reply, thank you! I'm going to try it

Comment: I have other issues with submodules, but I am going to accept this awesome reply

Comment: @zerunio for submodules, you could try `--recurse-submodules` in `git clone`.

Comment: it just downloads that repo,  but thank you anyway